# How to get row index of the selected cell in WPF grid

Tags: wpf, grid, devexpress

Does anyone knows how to get row index of the selected cell in DevExpress WPF grid?
In WinForms it was something like that:

```
dataGridViewControll.SelectedCells[0].RowIndex;
```

Answer (score 1):

Grid.GetRow(urGridctrl);